# 'getOption("repos")' replaces Bioconductor standard repositories, see '?repositories' for details

Tags: r, package, bioconductor

I am using this to install `maEndToEnd` package-

```
BiocManager::install("maEndToEnd", version = "devel")
```

It is showing-

```
'getOption("repos")' replaces Bioconductor standard repositories, see
'?repositories' for details

replacement repositories:
    CRAN: https://cran.rstudio.com/

Bioconductor version 3.13 (BiocManager 1.30.13), R 4.1.0 beta (2021-05-06 r80268)
Installing package(s) 'BiocVersion', 'maEndToEnd'
also installing the dependencies ‘formatR’, ‘lambda.r’, ‘futile.options’, ‘RCurl’, ‘GenomeInfoDbData’, ‘base64’, ‘htmlwidgets’, ‘futile.logger’, ‘snow’, ‘BH’, ‘fastmatch’, ‘tweenr’, ‘polyclip’, ‘RcppEigen’, ‘RcppArmadillo’, ‘backports’, ‘colorspace’, ‘patchwork’, ‘lazyeval’, ‘GenomeInfoDb’, ‘XVector’, ‘MatrixGenerics’, ‘DelayedArray’, ‘iterators’, ‘bit64’, ‘blob’, ‘plogr’, ‘bit’, ‘KEGGREST’, ‘gcrma’, ‘hexbin’, ‘BeadDataPackR’, ‘illuminaio’, ‘Formula’, ‘gridExtra’, ‘data.table’, ‘htmlTable’, ‘viridis’, ‘htmltools’, ‘base64enc’, ‘png’, ‘jpeg’, ‘systemfonts’, ‘BiocParallel’, ‘DO.db’, ‘fgsea’, ‘ggforce’, ‘ggrepel’, ‘tidygraph’, ‘graphlayouts’, ‘checkmate’, ‘bitops’, ‘farver’, ‘labeling’, ‘munsell’, ‘viridisLite’, ‘xtable’, ‘ape’, ‘aplot’, ‘tidytree’, ‘treeio’, ‘BiocGenerics’, ‘IRanges’, ‘GenomicRanges’, ‘SummarizedExperiment’, ‘Biostrings’, ‘affyio’, ‘foreach’, ‘S4Vectors’, ‘RSQLite’, ‘DBI’, ‘ff’, ‘XML’, ‘AnnotationDbi’, ‘org.Hs.eg.db’, ‘affxparser’, ‘preprocessCore’, ‘zlibbioc’, ‘affy’, ‘affyPLM’, ‘beadarray’, ‘gridSVG’, ‘Hmisc’, ‘hwriter’, ‘latticeExtra’, ‘setRNG’, ‘vsn’, ‘svglite’, ‘graph’, ‘GO.db’, ‘SparseM’, ‘DOSE’, ‘ggraph’, ‘reactome.db’, ‘igraph’, ‘graphite’, ‘downloader’, ‘GOSemSim’, ‘plyr’, ‘qvalue’, ‘rvcheck’, ‘gtools’, ‘caTools’, ‘gtable’, ‘isoband’, ‘scales’, ‘annotate’, ‘generics’, ‘tidyselect’, ‘cpp11’, ‘cowplot’, ‘reshape2’, ‘scatterpie’, ‘shadowtext’, ‘ggtree’, ‘Biobase’, ‘oligoClasses’, ‘ArrayExpress’, ‘pd.hugene.1.0.st.v1’, ‘hugene10sttranscriptcluster.db’, ‘oligo’, ‘arrayQualityMetrics’, ‘limma’, ‘topGO’, ‘ReactomePA’, ‘clusterProfiler’, ‘gplots’, ‘ggplot2’, ‘geneplotter’, ‘pheatmap’, ‘RColorBrewer’, ‘dplyr’, ‘tidyr’, ‘matrixStats’, ‘genefilter’, ‘openxlsx’, ‘Rgraphviz’, ‘enrichplot’
```

**I am using R version R-4.1.0beta**. How to solve this issue?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you will have to restart R. You need to see BiocManager 1.30.13.1 -- in the above I only see 1.30.13, so try again with devtools::install_github("Bioconductor/BiocManager", ref="ghost-binary-repo") and then start R again and try the phyloseq installation

https://support.bioconductor.org/p/9136936/#9136960

Comment: BiocManager 1.30.15 is on CRAN as of 2021-05-11, cf. https://cran.r-project.org/package=BiocManager